Multi Value Look-Up Column is not showing up as crawled Property
Hi i have the following issue,
i want to configure a pnp Searchwebpart. For that matter i have a List of Products and a List of Features. The Product is an aspx Site and has a Lookup Column to the Featurelist. The Problem is i need multiple Properties from the Feature to be mapped to a refinable string.
The Problem only the Main Value gehts exposed as Crawled Property. So i thought, ok then for each interesting Property of Feature i create another LookupColumn and map them like that. But in this case the other Lookup Columns dont show up as Crawled Properties at all.
The Lookup Columns having a Value, they are only textfields.
Have anyone an idea what causes that problem?
Thanks in advance

your lookup is a site column or a list column?

Its a site column. Actually its a column that is attached to an aspx Site. That seems to be the the Problem. I fixed it by creating an item with all the columns and a link to the aspx. The Lookup for the item are crawled as expected  and can be mapped to managed metadata
